# Apache deflate not working on debian

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, deflate

I have the deflate module enabled, it shows up in apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES, the config files are in the right place and some gzip testing tools say that it is enabled.

The only problem is the compressed size is the same as the uncompressed size (using curl --compressed -I http://www.site.com and curl -I http://www.site.com).

I'm running out of things to test. As far as I can see it should be working.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP and Apache were fighting it out for compression.

I changed php.ini to:

```
output_buffering = Off

zlib.output_compression = Off
```

and compression works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend use [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) Firefox plugging to debug. In it, you can see all HTTP headers and compare with the mod_deflate directives. Probably mod_deflate configuration error.

Also try log compression ratios:

```
DeflateFilterNote Input instream
DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio

LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
CustomLog logs/deflate_log deflate
```